# Laravel Jobs Stuck in Pending State on Horizon After Deployment on Ploi.io

Tags: laravel, jobs, horizon

I'm facing a problem with my Laravel project that I set up on ploi.io. The issue is with the jobs I send to Horizon - they just stay pending and never actually run. I already tried what others suggested, like checking if the environments match, if the queues match, restarting Horizon and so on, but to no avail. I have no idea what else to try so any help is appreciated.

My `horizon.php`  configuration is pretty basic:

```
'defaults' => [
    'supervisor-1' => [
        'connection' => 'redis',
        'queue' => ['default'],
        'balance' => 'auto',
        'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
        'maxProcesses' => 1,
        'maxTime' => 0,
        'maxJobs' => 0,
        'memory' => 128,
        'tries' => 1,
        'timeout' => 60,
        'nice' => 0,
    ],
],

'environments' => [
    'production' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'maxProcesses' => 10,
            'balanceMaxShift' => 1,
            'balanceCooldown' => 3,
        ],
    ],

    'local' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'maxProcesses' => 3,
        ],
    ],
],
```

Comment: have you tried running jobs manually to see if the problem is specifically with horizon or the jobs itself?

Comment: Yes, I ran the job from tinker and worked fine.